# a List item with more than one text field in python

Tags: python-3.x, join, intersection

Let's say you have a Python list of automobile manufactures as such:

```
['Nissan', 'Honda', 'Rolls Royce', 'Ford', 'Kia', ''Land Rover']}
```

The user enters a sentence as such:

```
I drive a Rolls Royce, a Ford, and a Land Rover.
```

The program is supposed to identify all automobile manufactures in the given sentence. The program uses set intersection to accomplish this.

The program returns :
I found 5 automobiles in your sentence
Your automobiles are ['Royce', 'Rolls', 'Ford', 'Land', 'Rover']

Notice how the output is unordered and split into individual items. I world like to re-join 'Rolls Royce' and 'Land Rover', but I cannot think of a neat clean way of accomplishing this.

Here is the code:

```
import string

result = []
autos = [ 'Mazda',  'Toyota', 'Volkswagon', 'Honda', 'Ford',
    'Chevolet', 'Tesla', 'Kia', 'Hyndai', 'Rolls Royce',
    'Isuzu', 'Jeep', 'Land Rover', 'Mitzubishi', 'Subaru'
]
print("original autos",autos)

### Split each item
new_autos = []
for auto in autos:
    new_autos.extend(auto.split())
print("\nnew_autos", new_autos)


### ask the user for a sentence
sentence = input('Enter a sentence with favorite automobiles of your choice: ')
title_case = sentence.title()

### remove punctuation
new_sentence = title_case.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))

### convert it to a list
sentence_list = list(new_sentence.split(" "))
print(list(sentence_list))


set1 = set(sentence_list)
set2 = set(new_autos)
result = list(set1 & set2)

### tried differnt apporaches to getting the discovered items back in their original order
###result = list(set1.intersection(set2))
###result = list(set1.intersection(set2))
###result = sorted(set1.intersection(set2) ,key=lambda x:set1.index(x))
####result = sorted(set1 & set2, key = set1.index)


if len(result) > 0:
    substitution = sentence.split()
    substitution[sentence_list.index(result[-1])] = 'Brussels Sprouts'
    print(f"\n\nI found {len(result)} automobiles in your sentnece")
    print("Your automobiles are", result)
    print("Your final sentence with some brussels spouts is:", ' '.join(substitution))
else:
    print(f"\n\nI found no automobiles in your sentnece")
    print("The automobiles found is an empty list:", result)
    print("Your final sentence is:", sentence)


# The output
original autos ['Mazda', 'Toyota', 'Volkswagon', 'Honda', 'Ford', 'Chevolet', 'Tesla', 'Kia', 'Hyndai', 'Rolls Royce', 'Isuzu', 'Jeep', 'Land Rover', 'Mitzubishi', 'Subaru']

new_autos ['Mazda', 'Toyota', 'Volkswagon', 'Honda', 'Ford', 'Chevolet', 'Tesla', 'Kia', 'Hyndai', 'Rolls', 'Royce', 'Isuzu', 'Jeep', 'Land', 'Rover', 'Mitzubishi', 'Subaru']

Enter a sentence with favorite automobiles of your choice: I drive a Rolls Royce, a Ford, and a Land Rover.

['I', 'Drive', 'A', 'Rolls', 'Royce', 'A', 'Ford', 'And', 'A', 'Land', 'Rover']

I found 5 automobiles in your sentnece
Your automobiles are ['Royce', 'Rolls', 'Ford', 'Land', 'Rover']
```

Everything looks good except, this is what I would like to see printed on the last line of the output

I'm getting this:
Your automobiles are ['Royce', 'Rolls', 'Ford', 'Land', 'Rover']

I want to see this:
Your automobiles are ['Rolls Royce', 'Ford', 'Land Rover']

I am not concerned about the order in which Python presents the intersected values, I just want to rejoin the original multi-word items - 'Rolls Royce' and 'Land Rover'.

Answer (score 0):

This can be more easily done with an alternation pattern of a regular expression:

```
import re

autos = [ 'Mazda',  'Toyota', 'Volkswagon', 'Honda', 'Ford',
    'Chevolet', 'Tesla', 'Kia', 'Hyndai', 'Rolls Royce',
    'Isuzu', 'Jeep', 'Land Rover', 'Mitzubishi', 'Subaru'
]
sentence = 'I drive a Rolls Royce, a Ford, and a Land Rover.'

print(re.findall(fr'\b(?:{"|".join(autos)})\b', sentence))
```

This outputs:

```
['Rolls Royce', 'Ford', 'Land Rover']
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ShadowyFlawlessExam

Comment: Thank you Blhsing.  I got this ['Rolls', 'Royce', 'Ford', 'Land', 'Rover']. for some reason it did not join' Rolls Royce' or 'Land Rover'.    This is the statement that I used: print(re.findall(fr'\b(?:{"|".join(result)})\b', sentence))

Comment: Don't split items in `autos` into individual words in the first place. Keep the original `autos` with the original names such as `'Rolls Royce'` intact. I've updated my answer with a link to a demo.